# How to use vertex.css.class option of render.3dmovie function in R

Tags: css, r

According to the documentantion for the [render.3dmovie function](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ndtv/functions/render.d3movie) of the ndtv package in R, for the visualisation of dynamic networks built with networkDynamic, it is possible to add css styling to the vertexes and to the edges. I am breaking my head over this since a couple of days because I don't understand how I can add the styling and where. I have tried to add it inside the function like this:

```
render.d3movie(net3, usearrows = F, 
   displaylabels = F, label=net3 %v% "Label",
   edge.lwd = function(slice){(slice %e% "Weight")/3}, 
   edge.col = '#55555599',
   vertex.css.class = {color: "green"},
   ...)
```

but this doensn't work. The knitr compiler does not give any warning, but in my html output I get this error message:

```
## Error in render.d3movie(net3, usearrows = F, displaylabels = F, label =  net3 %v% : object 'color' not found
```

I have tried also to use `vertex.css.class {color: "green"}` instead, but I get an error by the knitr compiler. So I'm out of ideas. I have not tried an external style definition because I'm not sure where to put it and how to refer to it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Not sure but this may be https://github.com/statnet/ndtv-d3/ contains custom style

Comment: Thanks Ajay, indeed I can see in the code that the vertex.css.class is used, but I still don't understand how. The example is much more complex than what I'm trying to do. If I understand it correctly, it is using a data matrix d, where class definition is stored inside this attribute called vertex.css.class. But then I'm lost, I don't know where it is using it afterwards, but I'd say not inside the render.3dmovie function.

Answer (score 0):

CSS styling happens in the web page that you embed the animation in.  If 
you were using an Rmarkdown file, you'd need to provide custom CSS that defines a style for the `vertex.css.color` class.  For example, define the style in a `styles.css` file and modify the Rmarkdown page header to include it
(see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#custom_css)

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    css: styles.css
---
```